# How can i look at query LINQ

Tags: .net, linq, profiler, linqpad

How can i look at generated sql query by LINQ? I tried LINQPad but as i understood i have to write LINQ statements into LINQPad.

### Any ways without SQL Profiler?

I use it here:

```
public IEnumerable<PeopleTalesCategory> GetAllCategories()
{
    return _dataContext.PeopleTalesCategories.OrderBy(c => c.PositionInMenu).ThenBy(c => c.NameAn);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using **Linq To Sql** you can use a `StringWriter` to get the Sql generated by the Linq To Sql. Here is an example that setup to the `DataContext` the Log and execute a simple query to finally show in  `sqlLinqToSql.Text` the SQL.

```
DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
db.Log = sw;

this.gridLinqToSql.DataSource = db.Customers.Where(c => c.CustomerID.StartsWith("A"));
this.gridLinqToSql.DataBind(); //Here is when the Linq query will be executed.

sqlLinqToSql.Text = sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
```

If you are using **Linq To Entity**, it's different. You need to call from the ObjectQuery the `ToTraceString()`:

```
var cust = (from c in context.Customers select c);
string sql = ((ObjectQuery)cust).ToTraceString();
```

Comment: It's not very good decision in my situation. I don't want to modify my code into repository file or make _dataContext class public, but thx.

Comment: If you have access to the DataContext, and you should to do your Linq call, this will be perfect. Why do you think you have to create "repository file" or something with dataContext public... You can do all that encapsulated.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernating Rhinos also has a tool that will do this for you (and then some: http://l2sprof.com/  There's also version for Entity Framework and NHibernate.

Comment: Tried to use l2sprof, but when i installed program, it coudn't find any data context.

Comment: Everything fine. This article helped: http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/csharp/LINQ-to-SQL-Profiler.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Just as a side note, custom enumerators such as IEnumerable Method() calls allow you to actually call "GetEnumerator()" method and return it.  I have used such constructs (using your example) as "GetAllCategories().GetEnumerator()" and use it.

Perhaps you can use the "AsQueryable()" extension method within LINQPad to see something a bit more substantive.